# javascript translate code into English

Tags: javascript

I'm a junior dev and am debugging a file uploader. I have this line of code that I'm having trouble understanding:

```
var ext = file.name.slice((file.name.lastIndexOf('.') - 1 >>> 0) + 2);
```

Could someone translate this line in plain English?

Thanks!

Comment: `debugging a file uploader...` <= on that note, try some different file name values for `file` and see what happens.

Comment: "Get the extension part of the filename in the most convoluted and confusing way possible, naively assuming there *is* an extension otherwise it will just return the entire filename, except the first character... maybe."

Comment: Split the line into smaller parts, and research what they do. =)

Comment: "Oh, and if `file.name` happens to *start* with a `.`, get the portion of the filename starting at character number 4,294,967,297". An alternative interpretation is "I'm installing job security", "I have no idea what I'm doing but it looks like it works" and "If you fire me I'll cause migraines in my replacement."

Comment: Okay so maybe I'm not giving your predecessor enough credit. Turns out if the filename doesn't have an extension, the 4-billion substring thing will almost certainly return the empty string - which again is the correct answer. And arguably, `.htaccess` is a filename in itself, not "empty file name with `htaccess` extension". Still...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol So, get the extension or return empty string?

Comment: Thanks to everyone replied.

Answer (score 0):

In one line, that code is trying to get the file type, by looking the extension after last dot.

Try the below snippet, you can easily debug javascript by splitting the lines.

```js
    var filename = "hellofile.12345.txt"; // = file.name;
    var indexOfDotB4Exten = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
    console.log('last Dot: ' + indexOfDotB4Exten);
        
    // Next step is more crazy
    // Ideally it should get Index of file extenion, i.e. next position after last dot (.)
    // Is almost equal to indexOfDotB4Exten + 1
    // But (1 >>> 0) will make sure your index is within range
    var sliceFrom = (indexOfDotB4Exten - 1 >>> 0 ) + 2;
    var ext = filename.slice(sliceFrom);   
      
    console.log("sliceFrom: " + sliceFrom + " ext:" +ext);
```